# Can I label the files in my perforce workspace rather than the latest revision?

Tags: label, perforce

I need to be able to reproduce a test case using the files that I currently have in my workspace.  So I'd like to label them.  However when I try to apply a label I can only see an option for applying the label to the latest revision rather than applying the label to the actual revisions that I have in my workspace, some of which have new revisions since I last updated.

Answer (score 2):

At the command line, run 'p4 label my-test-case' to create the label and name it "my-test-case", then run 'p4 labelsync -l my-test-case' to fill it in with the file revisions that you currently have in your workspace.

Comment: In the documentation for 'p4 labelsync' is says "The p4 labelsync command can only be used to tag files with an existing label."  So I think this might not be the right command.

Comment: Well, that's why I said to run 'p4 label my-test-case' first, in order to create the label.